# socket.recvfrom_into() TypeError: buffer is read-only

Tags: python

I call `socket.recvfrom_into` to get the size of a received UDP packet. The first argument is required as a `buffer` type.

```
data = bytearray(2000)       
packet_buf = buffer(data)
nbytes, sender = sd.recvfrom_into(packet_buf, 1500) # sd is a socket.
```

I got error "TypeError: buffer is read-only". 
I searched a while and didn't find much material of `python buffer`. How can I address this problem? And is there another way to query the length of a received UDP packet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bytearray` directy.

```
data = bytearray(2000)       
nbytes, sender = sd.recvfrom_into(data, 1500)
```

An easy way to get the size of the packet is,

```
msg, sender = sd.recvfrom(1500)
print len(msg)
```